# How to get the array object value in php?

Tags: php

I am new to php, for my android application I am using php. My problem is I can not able to access the array object value.
Store the select query table value like below

```
$rows = array();
$i=0;
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[$i] = $r;
    $i++;
}
```

When I display the value using `echo json_encode($rows);` it will display `[{"CurrentVersion":"0.0.1","ForceUpdate":"1"}]` this value. But when I trying to access this value in php I can not able to access I tried the below methods.

```
echo $verDetails[0].ForceUpdate; => ArrayForceUpdate <- I got this value
echo $verDetails[0] => Array  <- I got this value
echo $verDetails[0]->ForceUpdate;=> Nothing got
```

I want to get the **Forceupdate** value = 1. Please help me, I know many one feel this is the cheap question and you will put negative vote, but I don't have other option. I tried in many ways but I am not get any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mysqli_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) returns an associative array. So you have to access the values like this:

```
$verDetails[0]['ForceUpdate']
```

To use the arrow syntax, use [mysqli_fetch_object](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php):

```
while($r = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
    $rows[$i] = $r;
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have multidimensional  array try like this..

```
echo $rows[0]['CurrentVersion'];
echo $rows[0]['ForceUpdate'];
```

If you have json format data.use `json_decode()` to convert it into array.Then access each element.like this

```
$json = '[{"CurrentVersion":"0.0.1","ForceUpdate":"1"}]';

$rows = json_decode($json,true);
echo $rows[0]['CurrentVersion']."<br/>";
echo $rows[0]['ForceUpdate'];
```